# How to Handle Special character in config.ini file as variable in php

Tags: php, config

I have created one config.ini file with help of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

my file contain:

```
[first_section]
sourcepath="C:\wamp\www\mydata\"
filetype="csv"
Product="Product"
A & E="A & E"
```

And `My.Php` file is

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("config.ini", true);

print_r($ini_array);
```

when i call this php program it giving following Error

```
Warning: syntax error, unexpected '&' in config.ini on  in C:\wamp\www\mydata\my.php on line 9
```

I know i cant use special characters in variable . but i have to use this only .

so not getting how to do. Can any one Help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, characters like `&` can't be used as ini keys.

From the PHP Manual:

> Characters `?{}|&~![()^"` must not be used anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value.

See the documentation: [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file)

Comment: thank you.ya, I saw. but i want to use this. any way to resolve this problem.

Comment: @user2492230: **Why** do you need special characters as keys?

Comment: we are calling some xls files from another server and that file header contains string and those string contains special characters. so we need to map that with database table for that we want to add key as special character in that.

Comment: @user2492230: In that case, remove special characters from the string first, using a regex or similar. This may not be the answer you were hoping to hear, but it's just not possible (even if possible, not a good practice).